# application.ontime vba passing variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to pass a variable(string) to a sub which is in module1 of my workbook using application.on time method.
the below code is runing fine

```
Sub calar()
strText = "appl"
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "!Module1.cld"
End Sub

Sub cld()
MsgBox ("called" & slk)
End Sub
```

But when I try to pass an argument as shown below, I am getting an error:

```
Sub calar()
strText = "appl"
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "'!Module1.cld ""Hello!""'"
End Sub

Sub cld(ByVal slk As String)
MsgBox ("called" & slk)
End Sub
```

I want to pass strText as an argument please help.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://markrowlinson.co.uk/articles.php?id=10)

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the first exclamation point...

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "'Module1.cld ""Hello!""'"
```

To pass a variable...

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "'Module1.cld """ & strText & """'"
```